# Building an orthogonal embedding for a 4-planar graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry, discrete-mathematics, topological-graph-theory

I'm interested in the following paper http://www.computer.org/csdl/trans/tc/1981/02/06312176.pdf

In particular i'm interested in the construction Valiant describes to prove that it is possible to embed a $4$-planar graph in a grid of size $9n^{2}$ (on the top right of page 2). He says that the construction is described in fig 2, but i do not understand it completely. I was hoping someone may be able to explain it more clearly. One of my confusions with the diagram in fig 2 is how do we know the neighbours of the next vertex to be added namely the $(I+1)$st vertex lie on the border of the currently constructed embedding, what's to say stopping one it's neighbours being in the middle of the embedding?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but perhaps you are aware that the state-of-the-art has advanced since that 1981 paper. E.g., Cornelsen, Sabine, and Andreas Karrenbauer. "Accelerated bend minimization." *Graph Drawing*. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2012. They compute a min bend drawing in subquadratic time.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i'm interested in this particular construction however.

Comment: You have already asked the same question before (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/219260/construction-of-planar-embedding) which I already answered and you accepted.  Is there a reason that you are asking it again?

Comment: Hi, you said it was a graph with $n$ vertices but it should actually be $n$ edges, it says the size of the graph is $n$ and the size is the cardinality of the edge set. In addition what did you mean by the same outer face?

Comment: Would your original proof change in anyway based on the fact that you did yours with $n$ vertices?

Comment: My answer to your previous question is correct as written.  Same outer face means that the closed walks which bound the outer faces in each embedding are the same.  I suspect that Valiant momentarily mistook $n$ to mean the number of vertices in that sentence.  It is not a big deal though, since he simply wanted to prove that an $O(|V|^2)$-grid suffices, and in a planar graph the number of edges is $O(|V|)$.